# Can I include blank lines into the file when using YamlDotNet

Tags: parsing, yaml, yamldotnet

Is there a way for me to include empty lines into the parsed YAML file using YamlDotNet? What I have currently when I parse a file like this:

```
node1: "1.0"

node2: "some text"

node3: "string"
```

I end up with this as the result:

```
node1: "1.0"
node2: "some text"
node3: "string"
```

Is there a way for me to configure the parser to not ignore blank lines?

Briefly, I'm using the YamlDotNet Parser class like so:

```
var input = File.OpenText(file);
var parser = new Parser(_input);

public bool Read()
{
    Value = null;
    Path = null;

    var hasMore = _parser.MoveNext();

    if (!hasMore)
    {
        return false;
    }

    parser.Current.Accept(this);

    LineNumber = _parser.Current.Start.Line;

    return true;
}
```

And in a separate class:

```
while (reader.Read())
{

}
```

EDIT:

This doesn't only happen with blank lines, it also happens when I have a line break after a dash:

Before:

```
-
  name: Mark McGwire
  hr:   65
  avg:  0.278
```

After:

```
- name: Mark McGwire
  hr:   65
  avg:  0.278
```

Comment: What do you except by having a empty line. It does not container any yaml data. That is why parser ignore the empty line